# Unable to read connection string from appsettings.json in a console application

Tags: c#, .net-core

I was tring .NET core with a console application and I'm stucked on reading from `appsettings.json`. 
Here's my code:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DataBaseConnectionString": "Server=xxxxxx"
        }
}
```

...

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    //  .SetBasePath("")
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
configuration = builder.Build();

var xx = configuration.GetConnectionString("DataBaseConnectionString");
```

I got null on `xx`, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: If someone is also getting ```System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized``` error do this: right click on ```appsettings.json``` -> Properties -> Set ```Copy to output directory``` to ```Copy always```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is correct. Set `optional: false` to check the file exists. The keypoint for a console app is to ensure `appsettings.json` has `Copy to output directory: Always` property.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
//set "optional: false" to fail-fast without a file
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
var configuration = builder.Build();

//contains "Server=xxxxxx"
string str = configuration.GetConnectionString("DataBaseConnectionString");
```

Actual documentation: [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration)